# Can not change the display name of From email through smtp.office365.com using C# SmtpClient

Tags: c#, email, office365, smtpclient

In the past few months, I used **SmtpClient** to send emails with host **smtp.office.365.comn**, and I could change the Display Name of From Email using

```
message.From = new MailAddress(email, displayName)
```

But recently the client has found out that they can no longer change that **displayName**, the mail they received only show email (username@domain.com) in the **From**

So, is there any change from Microsoft or any way I can custom the Display Name?
Because my code runs well with Gmail (**smtp.gmail.com**).

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a test and sent an email from an address *inside* my organization, and the email message (displayed in Outlook) ignored the Display Name I had set, and instead used the display name that's set in our Active Directory for that account.  I then tested with a dummy email address, and it showed the Display Name I had set.  Could it be that?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I had. What dummy email address do you use?

Comment: You can use whatever email address you want (test@test.com), so long as it's not listed as an AD account on your company domain. Bear in mind that the client's mail server might block it as suspect, since the From address's domain (test.com) won't match the domain of the sending SMTP server.  A better approach is to register a new AD/ MSExchange email account that uses the Display Name you want to show on the From address.  ...or ask your AD/Exchange guys to update the name on the existing account.